# Angular 9 404 on a VALID route

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, http-status-code-404

I have a route that works in dev, as it should for example:
/view-entry/ 
in production, that same link (with a VALID guid) gets a 404.

Here is the router:

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'new-entry', component: NewEntryComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'view-entry/:id', component: NewEntryComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
];
```

The 'NewComponent' on the route is correct.  I use it to edit and create, and it works very well (in dev).  I only load data into the form, if the path is not 'new-entry':

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
            private apiService: ApiService,
            private uiService: UiService) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
const nav = this.route;

this.uiService.clearEntry.subscribe(() => {
  this.clearForm();
});

if (nav.routeConfig.path === 'new-entry') {
  this.loadEmptyData();
} else {
  this.route.params.subscribe(data => {
    // console.log('Id: ' + data['id']);
    this.loadEmptyData();
    this.loadData(data['id']);
  }, error => {
    //
  });
}
```

}

I have Auth0 authentication working on the site.  All other functionality (CRUD) to the DB through my API works great.  It is a very basic site, and there is very little to it. beyond entering some basic data and showing it.

All help is appreciated!

Brad

Comment: have you deployed the code in cloud ?? if yes try to redirect the default route  (in your cloud setting ) to index.html

Comment: Nope, not on a cloud server. :(

Comment: Do your other routes work correctly in production? What web server are you using and how did you configure it?

Comment: Everything works great, besides this one thing.  It is installed on a Plesk / windows server hosted by Interserver.net

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got it working!  It is all about the Router.  It doesn't like the href tags. I used href tags because I had no idea it would be a problem, and it worked fine in dev.  I changed it, and it works in both dev and prod.

Code that was changed (in the template for the list entry):

OLD:

```
<a href="/view-entry/" + entry.id]>
```

NEW:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/view-entry/', entry.id]">
```

I hope this helps people in the future.